# How do I convert output of number_format back to numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

PHP can't recognize `1,200.00`(generated by `number_format`) but only `1200.00`,

What's the general solution for this problem?

Comment: -1 to your comment @YourCommonSense , although I totally agree that formatted numbers is not something you want to store anywhere, sometimes you have to put up with rubbish code written by others and have no way to get around it and therefore the above has to be done. Your comment brings no value to this topic.

Comment: Also, you might need to display or input a formatted number in a form field, and when the form is submitted that value will have to be converted back to a number.

Comment: A common solution which is now already in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could remove any character that is not a digit or a decimal point and parse that with [`floatval`](http://php.net/floatval):

```
$number = 1200.00;
$parsed = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', number_format($number)));
var_dump($number === $parsed);  // bool(true)
```

And if the number has not `.` as decimal point:

```
function parse_number($number, $dec_point=null) {
    if (empty($dec_point)) {
        $locale = localeconv();
        $dec_point = $locale['decimal_point'];
    }
    return floatval(str_replace($dec_point, '.', preg_replace('/[^\d'.preg_quote($dec_point).']/', '', $number)));
}
```

Answer (score 22):

use ;
[Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

$number1= '$ 1,989.34';

```
    $number2 = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);//1989.34
    $number2 = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);//1,98934
```

Answer (score 19):

If you're using 5.3 or higher (thanks ircmaxell), use [numfmt_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php).

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function numfmt_parse()`

Answer (score 13):

You can use filter_var. e.g.

```
$num = '1,200,998';
$real_integer = filter_var($num, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $real_integer;
```

will output:

```
1200998
```

Comment: it's good if just we use the value with comma (,) numbers. but if the value have a decimal then `filter_var` also remove the decimal too from the value which is not good.

Answer (score 7):

You could do `$num = (float) str_replace(',', '', $num);`  Basically, just get rid of the commas, and then cast it as a numeric type (float or int).

Comment: What if the program is run in Germany which you may get `1.200,00`?

Comment: `$locale = localeconv();`, Then change the `','` in above to `$locale['thousands_sep']`...

Answer (score 7):

The better way is to use the options in `number_format` function itself. The format is

```
number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

I.e. if you don't need the `','` in the formatted string make, it is like

```
$num=23.33333
echo number_format($num,2,'.','');
```

If you need that as float then typecast the same to float

```
$floatnum= (float) number_format($num,2,'.','');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code:

```
function remove_non_numerics($str)
{ 
    $temp       = trim($str);
    $result  = "";
    $pattern    = '/[^0-9]*/';
    $result     = preg_replace($pattern, '', $temp);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can, use PHP `round` method like: `round (12.000000, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a functioning solution that would convert any kind of formatted number back to normal number in php.
I needed it to work with any kind of number.

So it took a while, but I wrote it.

It works if the number has up to 2 decimals, but I think that's enough.

Also it will remove any currency symbol and will only allow digits, dots and commas to be passed.

```
function unformatNumber($number){

  // works with 2 decimals max

  $number = trim((string)$number);
          $number = preg_replace('/&.*?;/', '', $number);
  $number_b="";
  $number_ar_prep=str_split($number);
  $number_ar=array();
  $separators_amount=0;
  $numbers_after_separator=array();
  $chars_after_last_separator=0;
  $last_decimals=array();
  $last_decimal="";

  foreach ($number_ar_prep as $char) {
        if((is_numeric($char) || $char=="," || $char==".")){
          if(is_numeric($char)){

            $number_ar[]=(float)$char;
          }else{

            $number_ar[]=$char;
          }
        }
  }

  foreach ($number_ar as $char) {

    $char=trim($char);
    $sep_increase=false;
    if($char=="."){
      $separators_amount++;
      $sep_increase=true;

    }elseif($char==","){
      $separators_amount++;
      $sep_increase=true;

    }

    $number_b.=$char;

    if($separators_amount>0){

      if($sep_increase){
        $chars_after_last_separator=0;
        $last_decimal="";
      }else{
        $chars_after_last_separator++;
        $last_decimal.=$char;
      }

      $numbers_after_separator[$separators_amount]=$chars_after_last_separator;

      $last_decimals[$separators_amount]=$last_decimal;

    }

  }


  $has_decimals=0;
  if(isset($numbers_after_separator[$separators_amount])){
    if($numbers_after_separator[$separators_amount]<3){
      $has_decimals=1;
    }
  }

  if(!$has_decimals){
    $clean_number = str_replace(",","",$number_b);
    $clean_number = str_replace(".","",$clean_number);
  }else{

    $decimals = $last_decimals[$separators_amount];
    $num_without_decimals = preg_replace('/'.$decimals.'$/', '', $number_b);
    $clean_num_without_dec = str_replace(",","",$num_without_decimals);
    $clean_num_without_dec = str_replace(".","",$clean_num_without_dec);

    $clean_number = $clean_num_without_dec.'.'.$decimals;

  }

  return (float)$clean_number;


}
```

Example output:

```
(original > unformatted)
1   1
2   2
2.00    2
2,00    2
2,31    2.31
2.31    2.31
24  24
24.00   24
24,00   24
24,31   24.31
25.31   25.31
244 244
244.00  244
244,00  244
244,31  244.31
255.31  255.31
2000    2000
2000.31 2000.31
2000,31 2000.31
2.000   2000
2,000   2000
2.000,31    2000.31
2,000.31    2000.31
20000   20000
20.000  20000
20,000  20000
20.000,31   20000.31
20,000.31   20000.31
200000  200000
200.000 200000
200,000 200000
200.000,15  200000.15
204,000.31  204000.31
2000000 2000000
2.000.000   2000000
2.050,000   2050000
2.500.000,51    2500000.51
2.000,000.31    2000000.31
24,30 €     24.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ircmaxell, I came up with this:

```
$t_sep = localeconv()['thousands_sep'];
$num = (float) str_replace($t_sep? $t_sep : ',', '', $numStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For input that may be either a string or a number:

```
function Intify( $prmIntOrStr ) { # return the argument as-is or without commas,
  # depending on whether it is a number

  $strTmp =   str_replace( ',', '', $prmIntOrStr ) ; # drop all commas

  # get whether the argument without commas is a number
  $bolNum =   is_numeric( $strTmp )                ;

  # keep one of:
  #   either the argument without commas when it is yes a number,
  #   or     the argument as-is          when it is not a number.
  $valRtn = ( $bolNum ) ? $strTmp : $prmIntOrStr   ;

  return $valRtn                                   ; # pass result back to caller
} # Intify

# set test value     ; show as-is            ; call function                  ; show result
$IntOrStr = "String" ; echo $IntOrStr.PHP_EOL; $IntOrStr = Intify( $IntOrStr ); echo $IntOrStr.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$IntOrStr = "123"    ; echo $IntOrStr.PHP_EOL; $IntOrStr = Intify( $IntOrStr ); echo $IntOrStr.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$IntOrStr = "123,456"; echo $IntOrStr.PHP_EOL; $IntOrStr = Intify( $IntOrStr ); echo $IntOrStr.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function format_number($number) {
    // First, replace comma with a dot.
    $number = str_replace(',', '.', $number);
    
    // Then, remove all dots that have multiple dots after them.
    $number = preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', $number);
    
    // Finally, convert the number to a floating-point number and return it.
    return floatval($number);
}
```

In the first step, we use the str_replace function to replace commas with dots. This is a standard format used to indicate the decimal part of a number. For example, the number 50,25 is converted to 50.25.

In the second step, we use the preg_replace function to remove all dots that have multiple dots after them. This step is used to correct any accidentally added or incorrect dots. For example, the number 10.250 is converted to 10250.

In the final step, we use the floatval function to convert the number to a floating-point number. This is necessary to use the number in mathematical operations or to format it correctly. For example, the number 155,25 is converted to 155.25.

```
50,25 > 50.25
50.25 > 50.25
1,500 > 1500
10.250 > 10250
155,25 > 155.25
1.550,25 > 1550.25
5,100.25 > 5100.25
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

use "[^0-9.]+" regex.

```
$formattedVal = '$9,99,999.99';
$unformattedVal = (float)preg_replace("/[^0-9.]+/", "", $formattedVal);
var_dump($unformattedVal);
```

worked for me.

Comment: There are other similar answers posted already. This does not add much value to a decade old question.