# Comma is lost after propagation

Tags: php

I have `$number = '345,6';` and `$time = '1';` After `$sum = $number * $sum;` the `$sum` becomes `345`, instead of `345,6` 
Why is that and how to prevent losing comma and numbers ?

Comment: You probably want 345.6 instead of 345,6.

Comment: Well, yes but now I have a number without comma after propagation.

Comment: When a string is converted to a number, it ignores everything starting with the first non-numeric character. So `345,6` is treated a `345`.

Comment: Use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format floating point numbers according to the conventions of your users.

Comment: @barmar Didn't knew that, thanks.

Comment: and tell me how do you want to preserve ,

like 123,4 *1 =123,4

and what should happen when 123,4 * 1,0=?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't store numbers as strings. Secondly, use a dot to separate the fractional part. Like this:

```
$number = 345.6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the English dot `.` instead of the Dutch comma `,`. So `$number= 345.6`

Comment: Dutch comma? How I could live without that until now? ;)

Comment: Well in the Netherlands and Belgium, people use the comma to separate the integer part from the fraction part.

Comment: Really? [/irony][irony] Just wanted to ask you about the English dot, can't find it on my non-english keyboard ;)[/irony]

Comment: \@CommuSoft `user:1077754`->location ... how can I `@username`? Don't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

As Tamás Zahola said, don't manipulate numbers as strings.

When you need to display them, look at number_format function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Example:

```
echo number_format(345.6, 1, ",");
```

will output

```
345,6
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you  want a reverse of number_format 
check this

that can do 123,3 to 1234

if this then follow 
[How do I convert output of number_format back to numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php)

and tell me how do you want to preserve ,

like 123,4 *1 =123,4

and what should happen when 123,4 * 1,0=?