# Converting number-formatted variable back to original format - PHP

Tags: php

I used number_format in a number. I want to know how to convert number-formatted variable in php back to its original format

I first used number_format. And I want to echo back its original format removing the number format.

```
$number = 500000
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

Comment: number_format. does not change the variable. It formats output string only

Comment: I want to add two numbers but first I want it to be displayed in a number_format but I can't add those two numbers.

Comment: This is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php). So please check the answer.

Comment: Common solution: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = 500000;
$formattedNumber = number_format($number, 2);
$getBackOriginl = explode('.',$formattedNumber);
echo str_replace(',','',$getBackOriginl[0]);
```

Comment: But there is still a decimal. How to do that?

Comment: please share that possible numbers

Comment: Replacing dot in explode with a space works. Thanks!