# Remove number formatting from a string

Tags: php, number-formatting

The following code will turn 1000 into 1,000:

```
$price = '1000';
$price2 = number_format($price);
echo $price2;
```

How would I turn 1,000 into 1000? I'm guessing it would be something along the lines of this:

```
$price = '1,000';
$price2 = remove_format($price);
echo $price2;
```

Comment: It will give a format like this `1,000.00` after `number_format` so you need to remove the dot as well or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @HailHydra That is odd as it does not do that for me

Comment: There isn't a magic function to do this without knowing what the format should look like (e.g. is `,` a thousnds separator, or a decimal separator), but take a look at the [Intl NumberFormat parser](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php)

Comment: There isn't already a function, but I've just answered your question, it will remove the `,` from the number.

Comment: @HailHydra:  Default is 0 decimal places.

Comment: @HailHydra actually, the number of decimals defaults to `0`. So it won't add two decimal places at the end.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes I did notice, my mistake, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert output of number\_format back to numbers in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php) -- Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2935921/1601332) if you're on `PHP ≥ 5.3`

Answer (score 9):

```
filter_var('1,000', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's something that is very simple, but I'll make it into a function for you.

You can do this by just using something like the str_replace() function to remove the `,` this is what I came up with:

Code:

```
function remove_format($text){
    $text = str_replace(",", "", $text)
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: or `$text = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "", $text);` if the number is really dirty ;)

Comment: Yes, you could also use that if you so wish to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I'd use something like this:

```
    $a = "1,000";
    $b = str_replace( ',', '', $a );
    if( is_numeric( $b ) ) {
        $a = $b;
    }
```