# Decimal lost while extracting digits from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract digits and decimal point from a string but the decimal point is lost when I am using following regular expression:

```
<?php
$str = "$40.0000";
echo $str;
echo "<br />";
$pattern = "/\D+/";
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
$40.0000
400000
```

I want to retain dot also. How to include dot in my regex?

Comment: so do you just want to remove the `$` from the front?

Comment: What you want you want to extract numbers or you want to replace anything other than number ?

Comment: Hi, please check the marked question and if it didn't provide a solution for you, edit your question accordingly to reflect the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '$40000.00';
echo preg_replace('/[^\d.]/','',$str);
```

Several good answers here, too: [How do I convert output of number_format back to numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php)

Comment: This `regex` is exactly what I was searching for... thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

There are two appropriate functions for this purpose. The first, round(), rounds a value to a specified number of decimal places. The function’s first argument is the number to be rounded. This can be either a number or a variable with a number value. The second argument is optional; it represents the number of decimal places to round to. For example:

round (4.30); // 4
round (4.289, 2); // 4.29
$num = 236.26985;
round ($num); // 236
The other function you can use in this situation is number_format(). It works like round() in that it takes a number (or a variable with a numeric value) and an optional decimal specifier. This function has the added benefit of formatting the number with commas, the way it would commonly be written:

number_format (428.4959, 2); // 428.50
number_format (428, 2); // 428.00
number_format (123456789); // 123,456,789