# PHP - str_replace not working in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a large array. This is an example part of my array:

```
13 => [
    'Discount' => '0.00'
    'Total amount' => '50,00'
    'Total Net' => '40,00'
]
14 => [
    'Discount' => '0.00'
    'Total amount' => '20,00'
    'Total Net' => '16,00'
]
```

I need to convert the commas in the numbers to dots. `'50,00'` needs to become `'50.00'` for example. What's an easy way to do this?

Note: I tried `$myArray = str_replace(',', ".", $dataArray);` but this doesnot work.

Comment: Loop the array and use str_replace.

Comment: Show us your attempt - the actual implementation, not just the replacement line.

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php

Comment: This is it. I dumped $myArray and $dataArray and they are the same. Is this what you want to see? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the `array` *value's*

```
foreach ($array as $key => $string) {
    $array[$key] = str_replace(',', '.', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a multidimensional array you need to loop nested with both the subarray and the value by reference.
Or have the subarray as the input in the str_replace. (u_mulder)

```
foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val = str_replace(",",".", $val);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/tSgSP

You can also add a check to see if there is a comma in the value before you replace.
Not sure if that will make it faster or slower though.

```
...
if(strpos($val, ",") !== false) $val = str_replace(",",".", $val);
...
```

Comment: `str_replace` can work with array as source item, so second `foreach` is not required.

Comment: That was news to me, at least news since I last knew it and then forgot it again.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $myarray,
    function (&$value) {
        $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }
);
```