# how to convert number to double in php

Tags: php

I am using third party API. it returns value such as 6,000. As you can see, when I save this value into database, there's an error, because of comma in the number. What I want to do is convert this number that has a comma in it to something like this: 6000.

What I tried: `$num = (double)($val);`  It's not good,because now it gives me number 6 instead of 6000. how do I convert ?

Comment: why would it be a double? 6000 = int, not a float

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Try this solution from [How do I convert output of number_format back to numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php)

Comment: Example using number formatter: https://3v4l.org/SGipD

Answer (score 1):

Just use `intval()`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php, https://3v4l.org/K49bI.

```
<?php

echo intval("6000") . "\n";
echo intval("6000.00") . "\n";
echo intval("6,000") . "\n";
echo intval("6,000.00") . "\n";
```

Becomes :

> 6000
>
> 6000
>
> 6
>
> 6

Comment: And there is the `floatval` companion, in case those digits matter after all

Comment: In the case of `floatval()` its a bit more tricky, since it does not take into account all commas and punctuations. https://3v4l.org/dmGYc

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `filter_var()`

```
$num = '6,000';
$real_integer = filter_var($num, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $real_integer;
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/HfAhN).

Alternatively you can use [**NumberFormatter**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) if you have to parse float value.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$num = "1.234.567,891";
$num = $fmt->parse($num);
echo $num;
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/bGnll).

Comment: this will return an int 100% of the cases try `1,000.1`

Comment: Yes! Then `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` is suitable.

Comment: Blatently ripped from an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php

Comment: FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT wont work neither

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$num = doubleval($val);`

```
/**
* (PHP 4.2.0, PHP 5)<br/>
* Alias of floatval()
* Get float value of a variable
* &Alias; <function>floatval</function>
* @link https://php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php
* @param mixed $var May be any scalar type. should not be used on objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1.
* @return float value of the given variable. Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.
*/
function doubleval ($var) {}
```