# number_format turns float into a string php

Tags: php

Just wanted to check if anyone has ran into this.  Making an api call and this foreach is turning the float number into a string.

looping in a foreach and k=>v is turning float into a string.

```
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $result[$v['category_name']][$v['data_year']]['gross_profit'] = number_format($result[$v['category_name']][$v['data_year']]['net_sale'] - $result[$v['category_name']][$v['data_year']]['net_cost'], 2);
    }
```

using number_format turns that float into a string.  has anyone ran into this?

removing the number_format keeps it at a float.

Comment: This is [as intended](https://www.php.net/number_format). You're supposed to use it when displaying a number, so a string representation makes sense.

Comment: you can convert it to float as `(float)number_format..`

Comment: ```number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] ) : string``` reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert output of number\_format back to numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935906/how-do-i-convert-output-of-number-format-back-to-numbers-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will sum up all the comments for you. It is the intended way of using `number_format`
Example:

```
$someFloat = 10.99; // Float 10.99
$formattedString = number_format($someFloat, 2, ','); // String: 10,99
$floatFromString = (float) $formattedString // Float: 10.99 - note that this might throw an error/warning depending on language culture used by your server
```

**The function declaration:**

`number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] ) : string`
`number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," ) : string`
Input is a float, output is always a string. 
[Doc. reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)